# POWERSHELL | Get Folder ACL for Users by importing them with csv or txt

Tags: powershell, shell, acl

i want to extend my existing script to get the acl of a folder by importing a csv with many users.
I got the following

```
$Users = import-csv -delimiter ";" -path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Users.csv"

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)
  {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null
$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$foldername.Description = "Choose folder"
$foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
    $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
}
return $folder
}
$o = Get-Folder


 function Get-FolderRightsForAccount([string]$dn, [string]$rootfolder, [switch]$includeInheritedRights){
$sids = @()
$sids += (Get-ADObject $dn -Properties objectSid).objectSid.Value
$sids += Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $dn | select -Expand GroupName
$inherited = @{$true=($true,$false);$false=$false}[$includeInheritedRights.IsPresent]
(Get-ACL $rootfolder).Access | ?{try{$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value -in $sids -and $_.IsInherited -in $inherited}catch{}} | select @{n='Folder';e={$rootfolder}},AccessControlType,@{n='Rights';e={$_.FileSystemRights}},
gci $rootfolder -Recurse -Directory -PipelineVariable f | %{
    (Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Access | ?{try{$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value -in $sids -and $_.IsInherited -in $inherited}catch{}} | select @{n='Folder';e={$f.Fullname}},AccessControlType,@{n='Rights';e={$_.FileSystemRights}}
}
}

forEach ($user in $users) {
Get-FolderRightsForAccount -dn (Get-ADUser $Users).DistinguishedName -rootfolder $o -includeInheritedRights | ft -AutoSize 
}

write-host
```

If i choose $User = read-Host "enter user: " instead of the first line the script will work, but now i want to import more user by importing a csv or a txt file.

What do i wrong?

Comment: For one thing you’re running a loop on each $user in $users but reference $users in the list instead of $user

Comment: how do i have to change my script now?

Comment: change `Get-FolderRightsForAccount -dn (Get-ADUser $Users)` into `Get-FolderRightsForAccount -dn (Get-ADUser $User)`

Comment: i already tried that before with the error message "Get-ADUser: The argument for the Identity parameter cannot be verified. The argument's identity property is null or empty." in my csv file, all usernames are on one line

Comment: We need a part of the content of your csv to solve that riddle

Comment: in my csv file, all usernames are in one line below each other without , or ;

Comment: do I have to adjust the csv?

Comment: You need to show us your (sanitized) csv file. From your comment, I gather this is not really a csv at all, but just a text file with usernames each on a separate line. Does the file have header(s)? What are these `usernames` you have put in? (SamAccountNames, Full names, DistinguishedNames, or..) Have you checked [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) to see what parameter `Identity` needs?

Comment: my csv does not have any headers. just each SamAccountNames on a separate line.I already tried Get-FolderRightsForAccount -dn (Get-ADUser $Users).SamAccountNames

Comment: how do i add a working header to my csv? how should it look like? i dont really get it

Comment: If it is just a list of SamAccountNames, no headers you should use `$Users = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Users.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

Thats what i got now

```
$Users = import-csv -path "C:\Users\public\Desktop\Users.csv"

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null
$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$foldername.Description = "choose folder"
$foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
{
    $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
}
return $folder
}
$o = Get-Folder


function Get-FolderRightsForAccount([string]$dn, [string]$rootfolder, [switch]$includeInheritedRights){
$sids = @()
$sids += (Get-ADObject $dn -Properties objectSid).objectSid.Value
$sids += Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $dn | select -Expand GroupName
$inherited = @{$true=($true,$false);$false=$false}[$includeInheritedRights.IsPresent]
(Get-ACL $rootfolder).Access | ?{try{$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value -in $sids -and $_.IsInherited -in $inherited}catch{}} | select @{n='Folder';e={$rootfolder}},AccessControlType,@{n='Rights';e={$_.FileSystemRights}}
gci $rootfolder -Recurse -Directory -PipelineVariable f | %{
    (Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Access | ?{try{$_.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value -in $sids -and $_.IsInherited -in $inherited}catch{}} | select @{n='Folder';e={$f.Fullname}},AccessControlType,@{n='Rights';e={$_.FileSystemRights}}
}
}
  forEach ($user in $users) {
Get-FolderRightsForAccount -dn (Get-ADUser -identity $User.SamAccountName).DistinguishedName -rootfolder $o -includeInheritedRights -$User | ft -AutoSize 
}
```

The output is the folder, the AccessControlType and the Rights but no row for the user provided in the csv.